# App crashes randomly when my UIViewController is popped and UIWebView not loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in a `UITableViewCell` and the app crashes randomly when I try to set the web view's delegate to `nil` in the `dealloc` method.  Can you tell me how I can fix this?

Here is the code for my `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    @try {
            NSLog(@"Dealloc");

            for (int i=0;i<[arr_searchdocket count];i++) {

                cell_webview *cell=[tbl_search cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
                [cell.webview stopLoading];
                cell.webview.delegate=nil;
                 NSLog(@"Dealloc row %d",i);

            }

        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [tbl_search setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        tbl_search.dataSource=nil;
        tbl_search.delegate=nil;
        tbl_search=nil;
 self.navigationController.delegate=nil;

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace of the error I'm getting:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38282f76 objc_msgSend + 21
1  UIKit                          0x2d3603ed -[_UIWebViewScrollViewDelegateForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 144
2  CoreFoundation                 0x29afe371 ___forwarding___ + 352
3  CoreFoundation                 0x29a2d9d8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
4  UIKit                          0x2d1a575d -[UIScrollView _getDelegateZoomView] + 84
5  UIKit                          0x2d1a5699 -[UIScrollView _zoomScaleFromPresentationLayer:] + 24
6  UIKit                          0x2d1a5655 -[UIWebDocumentView _zoomedDocumentScale] + 60
7  UIKit                          0x2d1a51a5 -[UIWebDocumentView _layoutRectForFixedPositionObjects] + 104
8  UIKit                          0x2d1a5007 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateFixedPositionedObjectsLayoutRectUsingWebThread:synchronize:] + 38
9  UIKit                          0x2d1a7445 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateFixedPositioningObjectsLayoutAfterScroll] + 28
10 UIKit                          0x2d1a7421 -[UIWebBrowserView _updateFixedPositioningObjectsLayoutAfterScroll] + 56
11 CoreFoundation                 0x29ab30c5 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
12 CoreFoundation                 0x29a0ccbd _CFXNotificationPost + 1800
13 Foundation                     0x2a76f3a1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 76
14 UIKit                          0x2d7c16c7 -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 554
15 UIKit                          0x2d7bff15 -[UIInputWindowController performWithSafeTransitionFrames:] + 136
16 UIKit                          0x2d7c3019 __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke644 + 428
17 UIKit                          0x2d18f8e1 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 308
18 UIKit                          0x2d18f4f9 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
19 UIKit                          0x2d18f40f -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 70
20 QuartzCore                     0x2cb74fe7 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 234
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x38806c6f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x38812553 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1322
23 CoreFoundation                 0x29ac0889 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
24 CoreFoundation                 0x29abefa9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1512
25 CoreFoundation                 0x29a0a9a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
26 CoreFoundation                 0x29a0a7b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
27 GraphicsServices               0x313a31a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
28 UIKit                          0x2d1bb635 UIApplicationMain + 1440
29 TaskTower                      0xc4379 main (main.m:14)
30 libdyld.dylib                  0x38844aaf start + 2
```

Comment: If you're using ARC (if you're not sure, you probably are), then you don't need to set any delegates or data sources to `nil`, since they are weak references and will automatically be unset when the object is deallocated.  I don't know the exact cause of the crash since there's no message in the trace you provided, but it looks a lot like an unrecognized selector in your `UIWebViewDelegate`.

Comment: Also -- although this is unrelated to your question -- it's a really bad idea to put a `@try {...} @catch (NSException *) {}` in your code.  In Objective-C, exceptions are typically fatal errors (usually programmer errors) that should not be caught.  See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html).

Comment: @EricGalluzzo [Viewcontroller  respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8a8dcd0 this is log when app crash

Comment: Aha, OK.  Is `Viewcontroller` the name of the class that implements `UIWebViewDelegate`?  If so, the error is probably because you're calling `[cell.webview stopLoading]` in the `dealloc` method.  I'd try just removing all the webview logic from the `dealloc` method entirely.  All the views and subviews inside your `UIViewController` should be deallocated automatically when your `UIViewController` is deallocated, and their delegates should be set to `nil` at that time since they are weak references.

Comment: app crash happed some time ago so i put  dealloc logic in another viewcontroller so app does not crash in that class but it happen another class and i assigned weak reference webview nut not assigned  uitablviewcell

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite understand that last comment.  Which class has the references to the `UIWebView`, and which class has the `dealloc` method in it?  And what crash were you getting that you were trying to fix by writing a `dealloc` method?  You might want to put this information in your original question.

Comment: Because your code is randomly. update code.